# Typescript compilation for module imports

Tags: javascript, typescript, node-rsa

I am working with an npm module (node-rsa), trying to use typescript. In the example for my module, I need to write some js like this (taken from the module docs).

```
var NodeRSA = require('node-rsa');
var key = new NodeRSA({b: 512});
```

However, when I type this in TypeScript:

```
import {NodeRSA} from 'node-rsa';
var key = new NodeRSA({b: 512});
```

it compiles to:

```
var node_rsa_1 = require('node-rsa');
var key = new node_rsa_1.NodeRSA({ b: 512 });
```

which throws the error:

> "node_rsa_1.NodeRSA is not a function"

I am having to write my own `.d.ts` file, as there is nothing on DT, so I am not sure if that makes any difference?

Comment: Have you tried `import NodeRSA from 'node-rsa';`?

Answer (score 3):

I tried this on my project and it worked:

```
import * as NodeRSA from 'node-rsa';
```

I think that's because node-rsa has a default export.